# Spring Cloud Config Server with Azure KeyVault backend

Tags: java, spring, azure, azure-keyvault, spring-cloud-config

I am currently working on setting up Spring Cloud Config Server. I have to demonstrate that my config server integrates with Azure key vault. I have done extensive research and based upon on that I can only find config server implementation with hashicorp vault. Can someone please guide me how I can implement AKV with spring config server?  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To implement Spring Cloud Config with AKV

> You can use azure Key vault Starter that brings you the ability to use the *encrypted values feature* in your remote property. The values securely stored as secrets in AKV. Also, you could use your Azure Key Vault as backend to store your properties.

Setup a [key vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-key-vault#create-a-new-azure-key-vault) and try to add secret with name of `application---default---master---simplekey` and value as `dummy` and open `application.properties` file along with this properties.

```
spring.cloud.config.server.azure.keyvault.uri=put-your-azure-keyvault-url-here
```

Please check this repro [spring-cloud-config-azure-keyvault](https://github.com/srempfer/spring-cloud-config-azure-keyvault) for more information in detail